# Multiple Images in JS image swap, mouseout wrong image

Tags: javascript, html, image, swap

I attempted to duplicate an image swap but the mouseout ends up being image 3 on each of the three swaps when I'd only like it to be on the last. Any help I can get on figuring out how I make the swaps distinct from one another so they are not calling the same image would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
//---imageswap1

if(document.images) {
    cars1 = new Array();
    cars1[1] = new Image();
    cars1[1].src = "car4.png";
    cars1[2] = new Image();
    cars1[2].src = "car1.png";
}

function swapping_pics(picture_name, value_2) {
    document.images[picture_name].src = cars1[value_2].src;
}

//---imageswap2

if(document.images) {
    cars2 = new Array();
    cars2[1] = new Image();
    cars2[1].src = "car5.png";
    cars2[2] = new Image();
    cars2[2].src = "car2.png";
}

//---imageswap3

function swapping_pics(picture_name, value_2) {
    document.images[picture_name].src = cars2[value_2].src;
}

if(document.images) {
    cars3 = new Array();
    cars3[1] = new Image();
    cars3[1].src = "car6.png";
    cars3[2] = new Image();
    cars3[2].src = "car3.png";
}

function swapping_pics(picture_name, value_2) {
    document.images[picture_name].src = cars3[value_2].src;
}


<div id="imageswap1" onMouseOver="swapping_pics('car1',1)" onMouseOut="swapping_pics('car1',2)" href="javascript:void">
    <img name="car1" border=”0” src="car1.png" alt="car1">
</div>

<div id="imageswap2" onMouseOver="swapping_pics('car2',1)" onMouseOut="swapping_pics('car2',2)" href="javascript:void">
    <img name="car2" border=”0” src="car2.png" alt="car2">
</div>

<div id="imageswap3" onMouseOver="swapping_pics('car3',1)" onMouseOut="swapping_pics('car3',2)" href="javascript:void">
    <img name="car3" border=”0” src="car3.png" alt="car3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple functions with the same name: `swapping_pics`, to solve your problem, you could add an id to each function, like: `swapping_pics_01`, `swapping_pics_02`, `swapping_pics_03`.

But this, doens't solve the mess that you have, instead of all that code, CSS can do that in a much better way ...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imageswap1" class="swap"></div>
<div id="imageswap2" class="swap"></div>
<div id="imageswap3" class="swap"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
// This class "swap" is general to all the divs
.swap {
    width: 500px; // This is the image size
    height: 400px;
}

#imageswap1       { background-image: url("car01.png"); }
#imageswap1:hover { background-image: url("car04.png"); } // Mouse over 1

#imageswap2       { background-image: url("car02.png"); }
#imageswap2:hover { background-image: url("car05.png"); } // Mouse over 2

#imageswap3       { background-image: url("car03.png"); }
#imageswap3:hover { background-image: url("car06.png"); } // Mouse over 3
```

Fiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/qnw6j/

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much and the CSS tip is appreciated too, you just saved me thirty lines or so i can clean up.

Comment: +1 Toni. And @user2056315, don't forget to select Toni's answer as correct

Comment: user2056315 CSS can be a great buddy, its simple and clean code. 
By the way, thanks @MichaelPeterson...